# Apache: Errno 13 file permission denied

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask, permission-denied

I use AWS EC2 to run my application "Neural network in art". To send images I deploy a website based on flask + virtualenv + apache. After sending the image on the server starts the script, which print each iteration and I want to store it in out.txt

`__init__.py:`

```
#...
def apply_style(image_name, style_name, iterations):
    command = ['"python ~/neural_artistic_style/neural_artistic_style.py', \
            ' --subject ', '/var/www/superapp/superapp/uploads/' + image_name, \
            ' --style ', '/var/www/superapp/superapp/uploads/' + style_name, \
            ' --iterations ', iterations, \
            ' --network ~/neural_artistic_style/imagenet-vgg-verydeep-19.mat"']
    str = ''.join(command)
    network = Popen(str, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    stats = []
    for out in network.stdout:
        stats.append(out)
    line = ' '.join(stats)
    return line

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image = request.files['image']
        style = request.files['style']
        iterations = request.form['iter']
        if file and style:
#Saving images...                
            result = apply_style(image_name, style_name, iterations)
            f = open('out.txt', 'w')
            f.write(result)
            f.close()
            return 'FINISHED'
#...
```

Well, I can upload image via HTTP without writing result in out.txt, but when I do, apache log shows this:

```
[Wed Jun 01 ...] [:error] [pid 2360:tid 14...]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Wed Jun 01 ...] [:error] [pid 2360:tid 14...]   File "/var/www/superapp/superapp/__init__.py", line 72, in upload
[Wed Jun 01 ...] [:error] [pid 2360:tid 14...]     f = open('out.txt', 'w')
[Wed Jun 01 ...] [:error] [pid 2360:tid 14...] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'out.txt'
```

All files in this directory now have 777 permission. When I try to write something using simple script like `script.py:`

```
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
f.write('some words')
f.close()
```

everithing works. But with apache it doesn't. Has anyone any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you restarted apache since the changes?

Comment: @RitLew: yes! sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Also, is there already a file named out.txt in the directory?

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the directory itself?

Comment: @RitLew yes, it has also 777 chmod

Comment: @RitLew Yes, this directory 777 too.

Comment: Try giving a full path to out.txt, I have a feeling that code might have a different working directory when apache runs it

Comment: @RitLew Okay) That works! But now I see another problem in apache log: /bin/sh: 1: 'my command which you can see above': not found. Do you have any idea, how to change sh to bash?

Comment: Which command is it referring to?

Comment: @ritlew /bin/sh: 1: sudo python ~/neural_artistic_style/neural_artistic_style.py --subject /var/www/superapp/superapp/uploads/image.jpg --style /var/www/superapp/superapp/uploads/style.jpg --iterations 2 --network ~/neural_artistic_style/imagenet-vgg-verydeep-19.mat: not found

Comment: You said you were using a virtualenv, do you have apache set up to reference it?

Comment: Can you explain, whay do you mean?) Probably I didn't.

Comment: Follow this link and go to the apache configuration: http://www.enigmeta.com/2012/08/16/starting-flask/#setup-the-server

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This might also be what you need to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450998/run-mod-wsgi-with-virtualenv-or-python-with-version-different-that-system-defaul#answers-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that apache runs your code in which will have a different working directory, one which you do not intend to write the file into. You must supply a full path to the file.

```
f = open('/path/to/my/out.txt', 'w')
```