# Flask deployment : no module name flask

Tags: python, flask

I worked for 4 months on an webapp and when I tried to deploy it, I saw this message on the server.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/wsgi.py", line 12, in 
>       from FlaskApp import app as application   File "./FlaskApp/**init**.py", line 3, in 
>       from flask import Flask, render_template ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

There is also this line I don't understand :

> !!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre
>   support !!!

So, I have the requirements.txt and the wsgi.py, do I have something to activate with a script or other ? Because I have the feeling that the venv is not activate on the server..?

Comment: try running requirements.txt file manually 
pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: You need to specify your python path in apache or nginx configurations.  if using venv.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450998/run-mod-wsgi-with-virtualenv-or-python-with-version-different-that-system-defaul

Answer (score 1):

Your error is telling you flask is not installed.

You can see what packages you have installed with:

```
pip list
```

Install with your requirements.txt:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Install flask alone:

```
pip install flask
```

be sure your wsgi is calling the right python executable if you are using virtualenv you need to set the complete path into your wsgi config.

---

```
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
```

This error is because you need libpcre you can install it like this:

```
apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev -y
```

then reinstall uwsgi

```
pip uninstall uwsgi

pip install uwsgi --no-cache
```