# wsgi:alert No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=XXXX): Couldn't bind unix domain socket '/usr/local/opt/httpd/logs/wsgi.xxxxx.11.1.sock'

Tags: django, macos, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

After upgrading Apache-httpd from 2.4.33 to 2.4.39 in Mac OS (Mojave), I am facing this issue:

`[wsgi:alert] No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=XXXX): Couldn't bind unix domain socket '/usr/local/opt/httpd/logs/wsgi.xxxxx.11.1.sock'`

Please let me know what configuration needs to be added in httpd.conf to mitigate this issue. As the server is not reachable with 503 error.

Answer (score 2):

After I added the following in line httpd.conf:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

The server is working smoothly now.
Ref: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-issues.html